# How to return nested data according to user role in django rest framefork?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have model which is connected to another model with foreign key, I have ApiView in django. Also, I have users with **admin,moderator** , and some roles.  What I want is when Admin sends get request bring all **nested data**, when moderator sends get request return only **one model's data**.

What can I do to implement it? I think to create several serializers classes to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple serializers.

```
if user.is_admin:
    serializer = AdminUserSerializer(queryset)
else:
    serializer = UserSerializer(queryset)
     
return Response(serializer.data)
```